# Job for nginx.service failed because a timeout was exceeded

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, systemd

I made a custom build of nginx with RTMP as [outlined here](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Getting-started-with-nginx-rtmp).

I created `etc/systemd/system/nginx.service` with the following settings as suggested on [nginx website](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/systemd/), slightly edited with my custom build location.

```
[Unit]
Description=The NGINX HTTP and reverse proxy server
After=syslog.target network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/home/ubuntu/nginx_working/nginx-1.14.0/objs/nginx -t
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/nginx_working/nginx-1.14.0/objs/nginx
ExecReload=/home/ubuntu/nginx_working/nginx-1.14.0/objs/nginx -s reload
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s QUIT $MAINPID
User=root
PrivateTmp=true
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If I just start nginx from terminal, nginx works fine.

Using systemd eg `systemctl start nginx` , terminal hangs for a bit, during this time nginx is working fine, however after about 30 seconds I get `Job for nginx.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.`

This timeout is false as nginx was running just fine during these 30s. I am unsure why it fails to detect that nginx has started?

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution myself.
For some reason, following error occurs `Can't open PID file /run/nginx.pid`

As mentioned in [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113319/nginx-service-cant-open-pid-file-run-nginx) the solution was to move my PID in the config to the logs location `/usr/local/nginx/logs`